# Why only First DIV appeared , How to show other DIV if order available?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have LabResults table and the order results belongs to departments :

```
Department number 1 = hematology Department
Department number 2 = Biochemistry Department
Department number 3 = Serology Department 
Department number 4 = Hormones Department
```

When I make new laboratory order and select tests some tests belong to department 1 and some belongs to department 2 and some under department 3 and some under department 4 , and some times the order include tests from one department or 2 department , the point I need in Result view to show the DIV and result if there is tests requested belong to that department for example:
When I made order number 5 and tests requested under department 1 , 2 only in the result view it should appear the DIV for department 1 and 2 only and hide DIV 3 and 4.
This is the view code and its not working as expected and only show first DIV and hide other div :

```
@model AljawdahNewSite.Models.Orders_Tables
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CashData";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPatients.cshtml";
    var hema = new List<int>() { 1 };
    var bio = new List<int>() {  2 };
    var ser = new List<int>() {  3 };
    var hor = new List<int>() {  4 };
    var culture = new List<int>() { 7 };
    var para = new List<int>() { 6,9 };
    var labPara = Model.LabParaResult.FirstOrDefault();
    var labCult = Model.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault();
    var labMicro= Model.LabMicroResults.FirstOrDefault();
    var labHema = Model.LabResults;
    var labBio = Model.LabResults;
    var labSer = Model.LabResults;
    var labHor = Model.LabResults;

}
@if (labHema != null && labHema.FirstOrDefault().deptid ==1 && labHema.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE.HasValue)
{
    <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">
        <h5 class="text-uppercase p-2 text-center">Hematology Department</h5>
        <table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().patient_no)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().RESULT_NUMBER)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.patients.FirstOrDefault().Patient_Name)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.labtests.FirstOrDefault().TestName)</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var employee in Model.LabResults.Where(x => hema.Contains(x.LabTests.Dept_id.GetValueOrDefault())))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@employee.patient_no</td>
                    <td>@employee.RESULT_NUMBER</td>
                    <td>@employee.APPROVED_DATE</td>
                    <td>@employee.Patients.Patient_Name</td>
                    <td>@employee.LabTests.TestName</td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
}


@if (labBio != null && labBio.FirstOrDefault().deptid == 2 && labBio.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE.HasValue)
{
    <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">
        <h5 class="text-uppercase p-2 text-center">Biochemistry Department</h5>
        <table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().patient_no)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().RESULT_NUMBER)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.patients.FirstOrDefault().Patient_Name)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.labtests.FirstOrDefault().TestName)</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var employee in Model.LabResults.Where(x => bio.Contains(x.LabTests.Dept_id.GetValueOrDefault())))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@employee.patient_no</td>
                    <td>@employee.RESULT_NUMBER</td>
                    <td>@employee.APPROVED_DATE</td>
                    <td>@employee.Patients.Patient_Name</td>
                    <td>@employee.LabTests.TestName</td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
}


@if (labSer != null && labSer.FirstOrDefault().deptid == 3 && labSer.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE.HasValue)
{
    <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">
        <h5 class="text-uppercase p-2 text-center">Serology Department</h5>
        <table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().patient_no)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().RESULT_NUMBER)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.patients.FirstOrDefault().Patient_Name)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.labtests.FirstOrDefault().TestName)</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var employee in Model.LabResults.Where(x => ser.Contains(x.LabTests.Dept_id.GetValueOrDefault())))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@employee.patient_no</td>
                    <td>@employee.RESULT_NUMBER</td>
                    <td>@employee.APPROVED_DATE</td>
                    <td>@employee.Patients.Patient_Name</td>
                    <td>@employee.LabTests.TestName</td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>

}


@if (labHor != null && labHor.FirstOrDefault().deptid == 4 && labHor.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE.HasValue)
{
    <div class="tab-pane container active" id="home">
        <h5 class="text-uppercase p-2 text-center">Hormones Department</h5>
        <table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().patient_no)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().RESULT_NUMBER)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.patients.FirstOrDefault().Patient_Name)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.labtests.FirstOrDefault().TestName)</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var employee in Model.LabResults.Where(x => hor.Contains(x.LabTests.Dept_id.GetValueOrDefault())))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@employee.patient_no</td>
                    <td>@employee.RESULT_NUMBER</td>
                    <td>@employee.APPROVED_DATE</td>
                    <td>@employee.Patients.Patient_Name</td>
                    <td>@employee.LabTests.TestName</td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>

}
```

The view output now shows only first department number div and not show other div if there is results for 2 department only show in view first DIV how to update the view code to show the other div if exists result.

EXAMPLE : 
Order number 50 has results for department 1 and 2 the view must show the result for deptid 1 and deptid 2 :

```
@if (labHema != null && labHema.FirstOrDefault().deptid ==1 && labHema.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE.HasValue) { } 

@if (labBio != null && labBio.FirstOrDefault().deptid == 2 && labBio.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE.HasValue) {  }
```

But its show only first one deptid==1 .and not show second one deptid ==2 
What is the error with the condition why not show both div maybe `FirstOrDefault()` the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following steeps to do this in the right way :

1 - Use just one variable for `Model.LabResults;`.
Instead :

```
var labHema = Model.LabResults;
var labBio = Model.LabResults;
var labSer = Model.LabResults;
var labHor = Model.LabResults;
```

Use :

```
var labResults = Model.LabResults;
```

2 - For each department, use variables and take the first element by department not just the first element, like:

```
var labHema = labResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.deptid == 1);
var labBio = labResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.deptid == 2);
var labSer = labResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.deptid == 3);
var labHor = labResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.deptid == 4);
```

3 - For each `DIV` use above variables like :

```
@if(labHema != null && labHema.APPROVED_DATE.HasValue)
.....
@if (labBio != null && labBio.APPROVED_DATE.HasValue)
.....
@if (labSer != null && labSer..APPROVED_DATE.HasValue)
.....
@if (labHor != null && labHor.APPROVED_DATE.HasValue)
```

4 - You don't need to declare collections for this variables, use just `ints` like :

```
var hema = 1;
var bio = 2;
var ser = 3;
var hor = 4;
```

Use this variables for **steep 2** like :

```
var labHema = labResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.deptid == hema); 
....
```

AND for each loop in the each `DIV` like:

```
@foreach (var employee in Model.LabResults.Where(x => hema == x.LabTests.Dept_id.GetValueOrDefault()))
.....
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Hello @Abdullah check this answer will helps you to use `.FirstOrDefault()` for each department and clean code.

Comment: Thank you so much its working , and i checked all your answers its all helpful :)

Comment: salam brother can you check this post pleas @Sajid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204142/translate-sql-server-select-to-linq-with-multiple-join-method-syntax

Comment: Assalam Alykum brother can you check this issue please and how to fix print issue from javascript code or from html properties or if you have another way to print out the data on the view page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62233448/how-to-print-out-sub-div-on-new-page-using-javascript-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Assalam alykum brother can you check this error please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62357738/failed-to-load-source-map-in-asp-net-mvc-after-publish-to-hosting-site   website link : https://www.aljawdahlab.com try click request home visit link its not open  @Sajid