# Translate SQL SERVER SELECT to LINQ with multiple join Method Syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, join

How could I do the join in linq from the following SQL SELECT statement by using method syntax :

```
SELECT distinct [LAB_RESULTS].ORDER_ID 
       ,LAB_RESULTS.patient_no 
       ,Patients.PATIENT_NAME
       ,labtests.TestId   
       ,labtests.TestName
       ,[RESULT_NUMBER] 
       ,TestsRanges.LowerLimit
       ,TestsRanges.UpperLimit 
       ,TestsUnits.UnitName

  FROM [dbo].[LAB_RESULTS]
  inner join LabTests on LabTests.testid=LAB_RESULTS.TESTID
  inner join TestsRanges on TestsRanges.TestId = LAB_RESULTS.TESTID
  inner join patients on Patients.Patient_No = LAB_RESULTS.patient_no
  inner join machines on lab_results.machine_id = machines.machine_id
  inner join gender on gender.genderid = Patients.Gender
  inner join TestsUnits on TestsUnits.UnitId = LabTests.UnitId
  inner join Lab_orders_Cash on Lab_orders_Cash.cash_order_id = LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID
  inner join PatientCat on (patientcat.CatId = Lab_orders_Cash.CatId)
  inner join Lab_Hematology_Samples on Lab_Hematology_Samples.SAMPLE_ID = LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_ID

  where lab_results.ORDER_ID = 2000000058
  and   (Lab_orders_Cash.catid = TestsRanges.CatId )
  and TestsRanges.machine_id = LAB_RESULTS.machine_id
  and  (Patients.Gender = TestsRanges.PatientSex or TestsRanges.PatientSex = 1 )
```

I stated the first part of the controller :

```
public ActionResult CashData(int id)
{
    var tables = new Orders_Tables
    {
        LabResults = db.LAB_RESULTS.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id)
                     .Include(p => p.LabTests)
                     .Include(t => t.Patients).ToList(),

        LabParaResult = db.LAB_PARA_RESULTS.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id).Include(t => t.Patients).ToList(),
        LabCultureResults = db.LAB_CULTURE_RESULT.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id).ToList(),
        LabMicroResults = db.LAB_MICRO_NEGATIVE_RESULT.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id).ToList(),
        labCashView = db.LAB_RESULT_CASH_VIEW.Where(o => o.order_number == id).ToList(),
        labtests = db.LabTests.ToList(),
        patients = db.Patients.ToList()
    };
}
```

The important now for me to join TestsRanges , TestsUnits , PatientCat, machines & Gender tables with this part on the controller :

```
LabResults = db.LAB_RESULTS.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id)
                             .Include(p => p.LabTests)
                             .Include(t => t.Patients).ToList(),
```

I created the complete relations in the database and foreign keys :

LabTests table contains Testid  as primary key 
the others tables include testid as foreign key LAB_RESULTS,TestsRanges and TestsUnits

This is class Orders_Tables:

```
public class Orders_Tables
    {
        internal IQueryable<object> result { get; set; }
        public Lab_Orders  LabOrders { get; set; }
        public Lab_orders_Cash LabOrdersCash { get; set; }
        public Lab_Sample_status LabOrderStatus { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<LAB_RESULTS> LabResults { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<TestsRanges> testsRanges { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<LAB_CULTURE_RESULT> LabCultureResults { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<LAB_MICRO_NEGATIVE_RESULT> LabMicroResults { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LabTests> labtests { get; set; }
        public LAB_RESULTS_CLINIC_VIEW labViewResult { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<LAB_RESULT_CASH_VIEW> labCashView { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<LAB_PARA_RESULTS> LabParaResult { get; set; }

        public Lab_Hematology_Samples LabSamples { get; set; }

      public IEnumerable<Patients> patients { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Customers> customers { get; set; }




    }
```

EDIT : I changed the query in controller as the following :

```
public ActionResult CashData(int id)
        {

            var tables = new Orders_Tables
            {
                testsRanges = db.TestsRanges.ToList(),

                //LabResults = db.LAB_RESULTS.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id )
                //             .Include(p => p.LabTests)
                //             .Include(t => t.Patients).ToList(),
                //LabResults = result,

                result = (from labResult in db.LAB_RESULTS
                              join labTest in db.LabTests on labResult.TESTID equals labTest.TestId
                              join testRange in db.TestsRanges on labResult.TESTID equals testRange.TestId
                              where labResult.ORDER_ID == id
                              select new { labResult.ORDER_ID, labResult.patient_no, labTest.TestId, labTest.TestName, testRange.LowerLimit, testRange.UpperLimit }).Distinct(),

            LabParaResult = db.LAB_PARA_RESULTS.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id).Include(t => t.Patients).ToList(),
                LabCultureResults = db.LAB_CULTURE_RESULT.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id).ToList(),
                LabMicroResults = db.LAB_MICRO_NEGATIVE_RESULT.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id).ToList(),
                labCashView = db.LAB_RESULT_CASH_VIEW.Where(o => o.order_number == id).ToList(),
                labtests = db.LabTests.ToList(),
                patients = db.Patients.ToList()
            };
```

but how i will call it in view code and foreach loop its not appear ?

this is the view code :

```
@model AljawdahNewSite.Models.Orders_Tables 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CashData";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPatients.cshtml";
    var hema = new List<int>() { 1 };
    var bio = new List<int>() {  2 };
    var ser = new List<int>() {  3 };
    var hor = new List<int>() {  4 };
    var culture = new List<int>() { 7 };
    var para = new List<int>() { 6,9 };
    var labPara = Model.LabParaResult.FirstOrDefault();
    var labCult = Model.LabCultureResults.FirstOrDefault();
    var labMicro= Model.LabMicroResults.FirstOrDefault();
    var LabResults = Model.LabResults;
    var labhema = LabResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.deptid == 1);
    var labBio = LabResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.deptid == 2);
    var labSer = LabResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.deptid ==3);
    var labHor = LabResults.FirstOrDefault(x => x.deptid == 4);

}

@if (labhema != null && labhema.APPROVED_DATE.HasValue)
{
    <div class="tab-pane container active" id="hemadiv" >


        <h5 class="text-uppercase p-2 text-center">Hematology Department</h5>
        <table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().patient_no)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.patients.FirstOrDefault().Patient_Name)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.labtests.FirstOrDefault().TestName)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().RESULT_NUMBER)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.testsRanges.FirstOrDefault().LowerLimit)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.testsRanges.FirstOrDefault().UpperLimit)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.testsRanges.FirstOrDefault().text_range)</th>
                    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.LabResults.FirstOrDefault().APPROVED_DATE)</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var employee in Model.LabResults.Where(x => hema.Contains(x.LabTests.Dept_id.GetValueOrDefault())))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@employee.patient_no</td>
                    <td>@employee.Patients.Patient_Name</td>
                    <td>@employee.LabTests.TestName</td>
                    <td>@employee.RESULT_NUMBER</td>
               <td>@employee.result.LowerLimit</td>  // how to call here
               <td>@employee.result.UpperLimit</td>  // how to call here 
               <td>@employee.result.text_range</td>  // how to call here 
                    <td>@employee.APPROVED_DATE</td>


                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>

}`
```

`
I tried another way to put the var result outside the var table and assign Labresult = result :

```
 public ActionResult CashData(int id)
        {
            var result = (from labResult in db.LAB_RESULTS
                          join labTest in db.LabTests on labResult.TESTID equals labTest.TestId
                          join testRange in db.TestsRanges on labResult.TESTID equals testRange.TestId
                          where labResult.ORDER_ID == id
                          select new { labResult.ORDER_ID, labResult.patient_no, labTest.TestId, labTest.TestName, testRange.LowerLimit, testRange.UpperLimit }).Distinct(),


            var tables = new Orders_Tables
            {
                testsRanges = db.TestsRanges.ToList(),

                //LabResults = db.LAB_RESULTS.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id )
                //             .Include(p => p.LabTests)
                //             .Include(t => t.Patients).ToList(),
                //LabResults = result,
                LabResults = result,

            LabParaResult = db.LAB_PARA_RESULTS.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id).Include(t => t.Patients).ToList(),
                LabCultureResults = db.LAB_CULTURE_RESULT.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id).ToList(),
                LabMicroResults = db.LAB_MICRO_NEGATIVE_RESULT.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id).ToList(),
                labCashView = db.LAB_RESULT_CASH_VIEW.Where(o => o.order_number == id).ToList(),
                labtests = db.LabTests.ToList(),
                patients = db.Patients.ToList()
            };



            return View(tables);
        }
```

but it shows error on the row `LabResults = result,`

```
Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable to System Collections.Generic.IEnumerable an explicit conversion exists are you missing a cast ?
```

Lab Result Class

```
public partial class LAB_RESULTS
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int SAMPLE_ID { get; set; }
        public int ORDER_ID { get; set; }
        public int TESTID { get; set; }
        public int GROUPID { get; set; }
        public string NORMAL_RESULT { get; set; }
        public int SAMPLE_STATUS { get; set; }
        public string EXAMINED_BY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EXAMINED_DATE { get; set; }
        public string APPROVED_BY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> APPROVED_DATE { get; set; }
        public string RESULT_NUMBER { get; set; }
        public string RESULT_REPORT { get; set; }
        public string RESULT_NOTE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> packageid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> machine_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> deptid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> patient_no { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> custid { get; set; }
        public string REQ_FORM_NO { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> serial { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string packagename { get; set; }
        public string UPDATED_BY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> UPDATED_DATE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> prio_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> update_count { get; set; }
        public string REJECTED_BY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> REJECTED_DATE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> REJECTED_REASON { get; set; }

        public virtual LabTests LabTests { get; set; }
        public virtual Patients Patients { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Labtest class :

```
 public partial class LabTests
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public LabTests()
        {
            this.Groups = new HashSet<Groups>();
            this.LAB_CULTURE_RESULT = new HashSet<LAB_CULTURE_RESULT>();
            this.LAB_HISTO_RESULT = new HashSet<LAB_HISTO_RESULT>();
            this.LAB_MICRO_NEGATIVE_RESULT = new HashSet<LAB_MICRO_NEGATIVE_RESULT>();
            this.Lab_Packages = new HashSet<Lab_Packages>();
            this.LAB_PARA_RESULTS = new HashSet<LAB_PARA_RESULTS>();
            this.LAB_RESULTS = new HashSet<LAB_RESULTS>();
            this.LAB_SEMEN_ANALYSIS_RESULT = new HashSet<LAB_SEMEN_ANALYSIS_RESULT>();
            this.LAB_URINE_ANALYSIS_RESULT = new HashSet<LAB_URINE_ANALYSIS_RESULT>();
            this.TestsRanges = new HashSet<TestsRanges>();
        }

        public int TestId { get; set; }
        public string TestName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Dept_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Machine_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TestType { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UnitId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TestGender { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TestAvailable { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> groupid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ID_sample { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> test_duration { get; set; }
        public string TestNotes { get; set; }
        public string group_name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> culture { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> test_status { get; set; }

        public virtual Departments Departments { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Groups> Groups { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LAB_CULTURE_RESULT> LAB_CULTURE_RESULT { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LAB_HISTO_RESULT> LAB_HISTO_RESULT { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LAB_MICRO_NEGATIVE_RESULT> LAB_MICRO_NEGATIVE_RESULT { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Lab_Packages> Lab_Packages { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LAB_PARA_RESULTS> LAB_PARA_RESULTS { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LAB_RESULTS> LAB_RESULTS { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LAB_SEMEN_ANALYSIS_RESULT> LAB_SEMEN_ANALYSIS_RESULT { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<LAB_URINE_ANALYSIS_RESULT> LAB_URINE_ANALYSIS_RESULT { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<TestsRanges> TestsRanges { get; set; }
        public virtual TestsUnits TestsUnits { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TestsRanges class

```
public partial class TestsRanges
    {
        public Nullable<int> TestId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CatId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> PatientSex { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CaseId { get; set; }
        public string LowerLimit { get; set; }
        public string UpperLimit { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int machine_id { get; set; }
        public string text_range { get; set; }
        public string panic_value { get; set; }

        public virtual LabTests LabTests { get; set; }
    }
```

testid primary key in LabTests table and foreign key in the other tables.

Comment: i think will be simple if you use just query Linq not methods Linq, because you have 9 join.

Comment: @Sajid how to use query link can you change the used code in my controller and add now one join with table TestsRanges  ?  with first table Labresults only.

Comment: Example to select distinct data from `LAB_RESULTS, LabTests and TestsRanges` tables :   ``var result = (from labResult db.LAB_RESULTS join labTest db.LabTests on labResult.TESTID equals labTest.testid join testRange db.TestsRanges on labResult.TESTID equals testRange.TestId where labResult.ORDER_ID = 2000000058 && ... select new {labResult.ORDER_ID,labResult.patient_no,labTest.TestId,labTest.TestName,testRange.LowerLimit,testRange.UpperLimit,testRange.UnitName }).Distinct();``

Comment: @Sajid in the controller i select tables from orders_tables class in the class i use IEnumerable with tables when i paste the var result  in controller it shows error on labResult  , labTest  , testRange   "the type or namespace labResult  could not be found are you missing a directive or  an assembly reference  "

Comment: i'm missing `in` keyword : `var result = (from labResult in db.LAB_RESULTS 
join labTest in db.LabTests on labResult.TESTID equals labTest.testid 
join testRange in db.TestsRanges on labResult.TESTID equals testRange.TestId 
where labResult.ORDER_ID = 2000000058 && ... 
select new {labResult.ORDER_ID,labResult.patient_no,labTest.TestId,labTest.TestName,testRange.LowerLimit,testRange.UpperLimit,testRange.UnitName }).Distinct();`

Comment: @Sajid when i added it to the controller under var tables = new Orders_Tables it shows error "Orders_Tables" does not contain a definition for result , i think i need to add result variable first under Orders_Tables  to use it here but what is the variable type ? when click show fixes shows , I added this variable to the class Orders_Tables  internal IQueryable<object> result { get; set; } and no error now in controller , but in view code result not appeared , how to use it in view /

Comment: @Sajid i updated the question with errors .

Comment: can you share the `LAB_RESULTS` class, you can't convert result to `LabResults` automatically. is `ORDER_ID, patient_no, TestId, TestName, LowerLimit, UpperLimit` in one class?

Comment: @Sajid I shared the classes , the tests done in machines and each test has reference range depends on patient ages infant,child,adults and elderely. and the range different from one machine to another machine and reagents in laboratory machine provider like roche , simens and so on

Comment: create SQL SERVER VIEW and use all the relations and put your SELECT statement in view then call the view in your model Orders_Tables and controller and your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve such errors and big number of relations just create SQL SERVER VIEW with all relations then add this view to your model view and controllers as one table no need to create any extra join and where and include in your controller just one call:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[LAB_RESULT_VIEW] AS

SELECT distinct [LAB_RESULTS].ORDER_ID 
       ,LAB_RESULTS.patient_no 
       ,Patients.PATIENT_NAME
       ,labtests.TestId   
       ,labtests.TestName
       ,[RESULT_NUMBER] 
       ,TestsRanges.LowerLimit
       ,TestsRanges.UpperLimit 
       ,TestsUnits.UnitName

  FROM [dbo].[LAB_RESULTS]
  inner join LabTests on LabTests.testid=LAB_RESULTS.TESTID
  inner join TestsRanges on TestsRanges.TestId = LAB_RESULTS.TESTID
  inner join patients on Patients.Patient_No = LAB_RESULTS.patient_no
  inner join machines on lab_results.machine_id = machines.machine_id
  inner join gender on gender.genderid = Patients.Gender
  inner join TestsUnits on TestsUnits.UnitId = LabTests.UnitId
  inner join Lab_orders_Cash on Lab_orders_Cash.cash_order_id = LAB_RESULTS.ORDER_ID
  inner join PatientCat on (patientcat.CatId = Lab_orders_Cash.CatId)
  inner join Lab_Hematology_Samples on Lab_Hematology_Samples.SAMPLE_ID = LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_ID

  where lab_results.ORDER_ID = 2000000058
  and   (Lab_orders_Cash.catid = TestsRanges.CatId )
  and TestsRanges.machine_id = LAB_RESULTS.machine_id
  and  (Patients.Gender = TestsRanges.PatientSex or TestsRanges.PatientSex = 1 )
```

Comment: Thank you its working database view the easiest way for relations and implementation than LINQ